# Expression for Energy associated to a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $a \in R$ and consider a sufficiently regular solution of:

$u_{tt}+au_t-u_{xx}=0$,  $t>0, x \in ]0,1[$

$u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$, $t>0$

$u(x,0)=\phi(x), u_t(x,0)=\psi(x)$, $x \in [0,1]$

Define $E(t)=\int_0^1 u_t^2+u_x^2 dx$.

Show that $E(t)=E(0)-a\int_0^t \int_0^1 u_t^2 (x,s) dxds$.

My idea:

We have: $E'(t)=\int_0^1 u_tu_{tt}+u_xu_{xx} dx=\int_0^1 -au_t^2 + u_{xx}u_t+u_xu_{xt} dx=\int_0^1 -au_t^2+ (u_xu_t)_x dx $

Integrating:

$E(t)-E(0)=\int_0^t E'(t) =\int_0^t \int_0^1 (-au_t^2+ (u_xu_t)_x dx) ds$

$=-a\int_0^t \int_0^1 u_t^2 (x,s) dxds + \int_0^t \int_0^1 (u_xu_t)_x dxds$

Then, I tried to show that $\int_0^t \int_0^1 (u_xu_t)_x dxds=0$ and obtain the result, but I don't get any result. Is this the right way?

Comment: You have that $E'(t) = \int_0^1 -au_t^2 + (u_xu_t)_x dx$.  The second term there is $u_x(1,t)u_t(1,t) - u_x(0,t)u_t(0,t)$.  But by your hypotheses on initial conditions, these are both $0$, no?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right! Thank you!

Comment: You should check your answer though... For example, what happened to the $-a$ going from the second to last line to the last line?

Comment: Oops, had not noticed. Have fix, thanks!

Comment: Still in this question, if we call $k(t)=\int_0^t \int_0^1 u_t^2 (x,s) dxds$, how we can show that $k'(t) \leq -2ak(t)+2E(0)$ ? I tried using direct integration, but don't get any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating
$$E(t)=\int_0^1 (u_t^2+u_x^2)\, dx$$
with respect to $t$ yields
$$E'(t)=2\int_0^1 ( u_t u_{tt}+  u_x u_{xt})\, dx$$
Your formula is missing $2$ and has $u_{xx}$ there. After substituting 
$u_{tt}=-au_t + u_{xx}$ we get 
$$E'(t)=-2a\int_0^1 u_t^2 \,dx 
+2\int_0^1 (u_t u_{xx} + u_x u_{xt}) \,dx$$
The second integral is zero, because the integrand is the $x$-derivative
of $u_t u_x$, which vanishes at both endpoints. 
Thus, 
 $$E'(t)=-2a\int_0^1 u_t^2 \,dx$$ 
which integrates to
$$E (t)=E(0)-2a\int_0^t\int_0^1 u_t^2 \,dx\,ds$$

---

1. Does the extra factor of 2 resolve or modify the question raised in the comments?
2. Comments by  Euler....IS_ALIVE are acknowledged.